# Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main

Tags: java, javafx

создаю приложение на ПК для своих целей, используя JavaFX. Среда разработки: IntelliJ IDEA. В idea всё запускается прекрасно, поэтому решил создать .jar файл для более удобного способа запуска приложения. Но .jar файл запустить могу только в idea используя "Run" (Показано на скриншоте). А в случае запуска файла непосредственно на ПК используя .bat файл - выскакивает ошибка: `Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application`.

[image: Запуск .jar файла через Run]

Comment: как именно запускается файл используя .bat?

Comment: Судя по всему у вас собрался "тонкий" jar.
При его запуске надо либо указывать путь к каталогу в котором лежат все библиотеки-зависимости, или собирать "толстый" jar, который все зависимости держит в себе. в maven для этого используется maven-assembly-plugin

Comment: @Эникейщик в батнике такие параметры: `java -jar AdminPanel.jar
@pause`. 

Вывод при запуске: `C:\Users\h1tec\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Личное\Приложение\AdminPanel\out\artifacts\AdminPanel_jar>java -jar AdminPanel.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class ru.MrH1tech.AdminPanel.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .`

P.S. Надеюсь правильно понял вашего сообщение и дал нужную информацию

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov есть ли какая-то статья для сбора "толстого" jar ?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-applications.html#package_into_jar - это как настраивать в Идее. Главная мысль собирать артефакт ` From modules with dependencies`. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/maven/maven-build-fat-jar.html - это про мавен

Comment: @MrH1tech да. У меня была такая же проблема, когда запускал без параметров -jar. А тут эти параметры есть, поэтому у меня нет версии :(

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov используя "заготовку" .pom файла указанного в статье про мавен, я получаю при запуске .jar файла такую ошибку `no main manifest attribute, in C:\Users\h1tec\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Личное\Приложение\AdminPanel\target\AdminPanel-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Comment: Что в твоем META-INF/MANIFEST.MF?
Продублируй туда значение Main-Class: 
вроде это javafx.application.Application

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov проблема c манифестом ушла (просто переделал .jar файл), а вот основная проблема вернулась: `Error: Could not find or load main class ru.MrH1tech.AdminPanel.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ru.MrH1tech.AdminPanel.Main`

Comment: А сам класс `ru.MrH1tech.AdminPanel.Main` есть в jar?

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov да, он там есть. 

P.S. Проблему с запуском через .jar файл (он мне больше не нужен) не удалось решить, но я создал .exe файл (используя Launch4j) и указал в него VM options такие же как и при запуске в Idea, теперь всё прекрасно работает. Спасибо за вашу помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему с запуском через .jar файл (он больше не нужен) не удалось решить, но я создал .exe файл (используя программу Launch4j) и указал в него VM options (вкладка JRE) такие же как и при запуске в IDEA:

`--module-path "путь до javaFX/lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`

Теперь .exe файл запускается и работает так, как нужно.