# Error: Could not find or load main class javaFX Intelleji Idea проблема при запуске скомпилированного файла

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea, jar

После компиляции проекта в файл jar он выдает ошибку, что не может найти класс Application в библиотеке javafx. При компиляции в jar архиве есть библиотеки такие как apiguardian, junit-jupiter, junit-platform, opentest4j.
Я уже много что перепробовал, но проблема не решается. Использую java-21,
скрины Project Structure:
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Вот сама ошибка:

[image: 5]

Текстом:

```
D:\Java\bin\java.exe -Dfile.encoding=windows-1251 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=windows-1251 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=windows-1251 -jar D:\IdeaProjects\FilesEngine\out\artifacts\FilesEngine_jar\FilesEngine.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.filesengine.MainFile
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

При запуске через параметры **--module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar <путь к jar файлу>** или только с одним параметром **-jar <путь к jar файлу>** выдает следующую ошибку, где в каждом упоминании javafx библиотеки выдает Unknown Source:

```
PS D:\IdeaProjects\FilesEngine> java -jar out\artifacts\FilesEngine_jar\FilesEngine.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/example/filesengine/MainFile has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 65.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

В начале написано, что неподходящая версия класса и java VM, но у них у обоих одинаковая версия (JDK 21).

Компилирую через артефакт в jar:

[image: 6]

содержимое pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>FilesEngine</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>FilesEngine</name>
<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<junit.version>5.10.0</junit.version>  </properties>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
  <version>20-ea+2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
  <version>21</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
  <version>21</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
  <version>21</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
  <version>21</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
  <version>21</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
  <version>21</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
  <version>21</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
  <version>${junit.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <version>${junit.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>  </dependencies>
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>21</source>
      <target>21</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
        <id>default-cli</id>
        <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.example.filesengine/com.example.filesengine.MainFile</mainClass>
          <launcher>app</launcher>
          <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
          <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
          <noManPages>true</noManPages>
          <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
          <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
        </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      </plugin>
      </plugins>
      </build>
      </project>
```

Сам jar архив:[image: 7]
Помогите, пожалуйста,
заранее спасибо.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 2. [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Comment: Вероятно, дубликат вопросов: [Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1300114/); [Создание desktop приложения с помощью JavaFX](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1304992/).  Судя по строке запуска, не указан путь к модулю JavaFX и не добавлены требуемые модули: `--module-path "путь к javaFX/lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`

Comment: я читал их, но они ничем не помогли

Comment: я запускал уже таким способом, но мне выдало Unknown Source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перезапустил интелледжи идею и все заработало